# How to create a script to change all sites in SharePoint Online to UK locale

Tags: function, powershell, locale, sharepoint-online

When creating a new SPO site in our tenant, the site is created with correct UK time zone, but the region locale is set to US, which means that the date formats, first day of the week etc are in US format. This causes problems with files uploaded there, containing dates etc.

I have a PowerShell to change locale per site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite
$LocaleId = 2057 # UK
$TimeZoneId = 2 # London

$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RegionalSettings,RegionalSettings.TimeZones
$timeZone = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $TimeZoneId}
$web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = $LocaleId
$web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $timeZone
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

This code should update individual site (not tested yet).

I would like the code to iterate through all existing SharePoint sites and change the locale of all US to UK locale as per code above, rather than a single site.

What would be the best way to do that?
Or may be convert it into function from the code?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below script to loop through all sites and change the locale

```
$LocaleId = 2057 # UK
$TimeZoneId = 2 # London
$credentials = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite -Credentials $credentials
$sites=Get-PnPTenantSite
foreach($site in $sites){
Connect-PnPOnline $site.Url -Credentials $credentials
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RegionalSettings,RegionalSettings.TimeZones
$timeZone = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $TimeZoneId}
$web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = $LocaleId
$web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $timeZone
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Michel Han_MSFT!
Just to clarify - Line 4 - do I connect to SP Admin site - i.e. https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com, rather than specific site?

I was looking at something as $SitesCollection = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
But seems $sites=Get-PnPTenantSite might be better...
Thanks again!

Comment: You could  connect to any site, the command $sites=Get-PnPTenantSite would return all site collections. And if my answer helps you, please accept it.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you - the script worked.
Problem is - OneDrive sites came "Access Denied".
So I was thinking to insert a line to add my account as secondary admin, run your script to change the locale and when all sites (incl OneDrive sites) have been updated, to add a line to remove my account as a secondary admin. 
Something:
$adminAcctToAdd = "user.mane@domain.com"
Set-SPOUser -Site $Web.PersonalUrl -LoginName $adminAcctToAdd -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
...your script..
Set-SPOUser -Site $url.PersonalUrl -LoginName $adminAcctToRemove -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $false
Any help,please?